# Форма перестает реагировать на все события

Tags: java, android

Есть форма в приложении очень простая. Нас интересуют 2 события `OnResume` и `OnClick`. Есть класс `AsyncTask`, который вызывается в этих двух событиях. Перед вызовом идет запись в лог, о начале вызова.
Возникла очень странная проблема. Если приложение работает уже несколько дней, то ни одно событие не наступает. Нет даже записи в лог, о том что кнопка нажата в `OnClick`.
Подскажите куда копать. Вообще ни малейшего представления.
Отладчик не запустить, потому что сразу после перезапуска приложения все ок.

```
public class Schedule extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

SimpleDateFormat sdf, sdfTime;
Cursor cMainList;
Date currentDate;
EditText etDate;
private View mProgressView;
ListView lvGroupList;

public final static String LOG_TAG = "KnowHowApp";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_attendance_list);

    mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.pbLoadingProgress);

    lvGroupList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGroupList);
    //lvGroupList.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(getString(R.string.dateFormat));
    sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    currentDate = new Date();
    etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
    etDate.setText(sdf.format(currentDate));

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    actionBar.setTitle("Расписание");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    // Закрываем подключение и курсор
   // dbHelper.close();
    if (cMainList != null) cMainList.close();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    showProgress(true);
    LoadSchedule loadSchedule = new LoadSchedule(this);
    loadSchedule.execute(currentDate);

   // DefaultAcion da = new DefaultAcion(this);
   // new Thread(da).start();
}

void showSchedule(JSONArray jsonArray) {

    if (jsonArray == null) return;

    //SimpleDateFormat sdfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    // находим список
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvGroupList);

    // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру

    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(
            jsonArray.length());
    Map<String, Object> m;

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject row = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put("startTime", row.getString("startTime"));
            m.put("groupName", row.getString("group"));
            data.add(m);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    };

    // формируем столбцы сопоставления
    String[] from = new String[] {"startTime", "groupName"};
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.tvCaption, R.id.tvInfo };

    // создаем адаптер
    SimpleAdapter sAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.activity_list_element,
            from, to);

    lvMain.setAdapter(sAdapter);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    Calendar calendar;
    LoadSchedule loadSchedule = new LoadSchedule(this);

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnDatePast:
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(currentDate);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
            currentDate = calendar.getTime();
            etDate.setText(sdf.format(currentDate));

            showProgress(true);
            loadSchedule.execute(currentDate);
            break;
        case R.id.btnDateFuture:
            MainClass.addLog("btnDateFuture pushed");

            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(currentDate);
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            currentDate = calendar.getTime();
            etDate.setText(sdf.format(currentDate));

            showProgress(true);
            loadSchedule.execute(currentDate);
            break;

    }
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //Intent intent = new Intent(this, GroupItem.class);
   // intent.putExtra("rowID", id);

   // startActivity(intent);
   //        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "itemClick: id = " + id);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {

    Intent intent;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private void showProgress(final boolean show) {
    // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
    // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
    // the progress spinner.
    //        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
        int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

        lvGroupList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        lvGroupList.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                lvGroupList.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        });

 //        }
}

public class LoadSchedule extends AsyncTask<Date, Void, Wrapper> {

    Context context;

    LoadSchedule(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(Date... params) {

        MainClass.addLog("LoadSchedule started");

        Wrapper wrResult = new Wrapper();
        wrResult.success = false;

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(context.getString(R.string.dateFormat));

        try {

            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("date", sdf.format(params[0]));
            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);

            Bundle answer = MainClass.sendPostRequest("getShedule", jsonArray.toString());

            MainClass.addLog("sendPostRequest getShedule passed");

            if (!answer.get("code").equals("200")){
                wrResult.success = false;
                return wrResult;
            }


            try{
                wrResult.jsonAnswer = new JSONArray(answer.getString("body"));
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                wrResult.success = false;
                MainClass.addLog(e);
                return wrResult;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            wrResult.success = false;
            MainClass.addLog(e);
            return wrResult;
        }

        wrResult.success = true;
        return wrResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper wrResult) {
        showProgress(false);

        if (wrResult.success) {
            showSchedule(wrResult.jsonAnswer);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Нет соединения с сервером", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        showProgress(false);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Нет соединения с сервером", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}

public class Wrapper
{
    public boolean success;
    public JSONArray jsonAnswer;
}

}
```

Comment: То есть приложение перестает адекватно работать после примерно нескольких дней работы? А другие функциональности приложения продолжают работать?

Comment: А весь код можно посмотреть, а не кусочек.

Comment: На остальных формах та же проблема. Кнопки некоторые срабатывают, но процедуры связанные с AsyncTask не отрабатывают. Выбрал одну эту форму для выявления проблемы.

Comment: `Отладчик не запустить, потому что сразу после перезапуска приложения все ок` -- можно подключить отладчик к процессу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо post_zeew за подсказку о возможности подключить отладчик к процессу. 
MainClass статический класс, в котором хранился контекст в переменной и конечно со временем он терялся (= null). 
Решение в 2-х словах получение и сохранение контекста OnResume главной активити.